# Mount errors when trying to open a DVD - is the unit broken?

Tags: mount, dvd

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04. When I open a particular DVD in nautilus i get this error.

```
    Error mounting /dev/sr0 at /media/user/L'ECO DEL SILENZIO: Command-line `mount -t "udf" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,iocharset=utf8,umask=0077" "/dev/sr0" "/media/user/L'ECO DEL SILENZIO"' exited with non-zero exit status 32: mount: block device /dev/sr0 is write-protected, mounting read-only
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sr0,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so
```

I tried to identify the problem:

```
    dmesg | tail
[ 2158.291448] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0]  
[ 2158.291450] Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
[ 2158.291454] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0]  
[ 2158.291456] Add. Sense: No seek complete
[ 2158.291458] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] CDB: 
[ 2158.291463] Read(10): 28 00 00 00 02 70 00 00 01 00
[ 2158.291471] end_request: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 2496
[ 2158.291501] UDF-fs: error (device sr0): udf_read_tagged: read failed, block=512, location=512
[ 2158.291505] UDF-fs: warning (device sr0): udf_load_vrs: No anchor found
[ 2158.291508] UDF-fs: warning (device sr0): udf_fill_super: No partition found (1)


Script iniziato su lun 25 gen 2016 08:04:57 CET

cd-drive version 0.83 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Copyright (c) 2003, 2004, 2005, 2007, 2008, 2011 R. Bernstein
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
The driver selected is GNU/Linux
The default device for this driver is /dev/cdrom

Drivers available...
  GNU/Linux ioctl and MMC driver     
  cdrdao (TOC) disk image driver     
  bin/cuesheet disk image driver     
  Nero NRG disk image driver         

CD-ROM drive supports some nonstandard or degenerate set of MMC

                       Drive: /dev/cdrom
Vendor                      : MATSHITA
Model                       : DVD-RAM UJ880AS 
Revision                    : 1.22
Profile List Feature
    Re-writable DVD
    DVD+R Double Layer - DVD Recordable Double Layer
    DVD+R - DVD Recordable
    DVD+RW - DVD Rewritable
    DVD-R - Double-layer Jump Recording
    DVD-R - Double-Layer Sequential Recording
    Re-recordable DVD using Restricted Overwrite
    Re-recordable DVD using Sequential Recording
    Re-recordable DVD using Sequential recording
    Read only DVD - on
    CD-RW Re-writable Compact Disc capable
    Write once Compact Disc capable
    Read only Compact Disc capable

Core Feature

Morphing Feature
    Operational Change Request/Notification supported
    Synchronous GET EVENT/STATUS NOTIFICATION supported

Removable Medium Feature
    Tray type loading mechanism
    can eject the medium or magazine via the normal START/STOP command
    can be locked into the Logical Unit

Write Protect Feature

Random Readable Feature

Multi-Read Feature

CD Read Feature
    C2 Error pointers are supported
    CD-Text is supported

DVD Read Feature

Random Writable Feature

Incremental Streaming Writable Feature

Formattable Feature

Management Ability of the Logical Unit/media system to provide an apparently defect-free space. Feature

Restricted Overwrite Feature

DVD+RW Feature

DVD+R Feature

Rigid Restricted Overwrite Feature

CD Track at Once Feature

CD Mastering (Session at Once) Feature

DVD-R/RW Write Feature

Unknown code 33 Feature

Core Feature

Profile List Feature
    disk Re-writable; with removable media
    Unknown Profile 0 - on
    Unknown Profile 8013 - on
    Unknown Profile 88 - on
    Unknown Profile 24 - on
    Unknown Profile 88 - on
    Unknown Profile 1900
    Unknown Profile 0
    Unknown Profile 0
    Unknown Profile fdff
    Unknown Profile a05c - on
    Unknown Profile 88 - on
    Unknown Profile 1024 - on
    The Logical Unit does not conform to any Profile - on
    Non-removable
    Unknown Profile 0 - on
    disk Re-writable; with removable media
    Unknown Profile 0 - on
    Unknown Profile 4070 - on
    Unknown Profile 188 - on
    Unknown Profile 4d - on
    Unknown Profile 88 - on
    Unknown Profile db00
    Unknown Profile 0
    Unknown Profile 0
    Unknown Profile 8b08 - on
    Unknown Profile f0fa - on
    Unknown Profile 188 - on
    Unknown Profile 1024 - on
    The Logical Unit does not conform to any Profile - on
    Non-removable
    Unknown Profile 0 - on
    disk Re-writable; with removable media
    Unknown Profile 0 - on
    Unknown Profile c0f7
    Unknown Profile 88 - on
    Unknown Profile 8b - on
    Unknown Profile 88 - on
    Unknown Profile db00
    Unknown Profile 0
    Unknown Profile 0
    Unknown Profile d300
    Unknown Profile f0fa - on
    Unknown Profile 188 - on
    Unknown Profile 1024 - on
    The Logical Unit does not conform to any Profile - on
    Non-removable
    Unknown Profile 0 - on
    disk Re-writable; with removable media
    Unknown Profile 0 - on
    Unknown Profile c047
    Unknown Profile 88 - on
    Unknown Profile 38
    Unknown Profile 188 - on
    Unknown Profile db00

Hardware                                  : CD-ROM or DVD
Can eject                                 : Yes
Can close tray                            : Yes
Can disable manual eject                  : Yes
Can select juke-box disc                  : No

Can set drive speed                       : No
Can read multiple sessions (e.g. PhotoCD) : Yes
Can hard reset device                     : Yes

Reading....
  Can read Mode 2 Form 1                  : Yes
  Can read Mode 2 Form 2                  : Yes
  Can read (S)VCD (i.e. Mode 2 Form 1/2)  : Yes
  Can read C2 Errors                      : Yes
  Can read IRSC                           : Yes
  Can read Media Channel Number (or UPC)  : Yes
  Can play audio                          : Yes
  Can read CD-DA                          : Yes
  Can read CD-R                           : Yes
  Can read CD-RW                          : Yes
  Can read DVD-ROM                        : Yes

Writing....
  Can write CD-RW                         : Yes
  Can write DVD-R                         : Yes
  Can write DVD-RAM                       : Yes
  Can write DVD-RW                        : No
  Can write DVD+RW                        : No


exit
Script effettuato su lun 25 gen 2016 08:05:12 CET
```

Can you help me identify the problem?

Comment: Have you tried another CD/DVD with data that's readable, because you wrote it onto that? Can you see the DVD-drive in the BIOS?

Comment: I am afk  right now. I tried that Dvd on my laptop and it's fine. I'll dig hdpharm since I think is mount related.

Comment: i found the solution. i am editing the original question

Comment: It's recommended that you create an answer, rather than edit the question. That way, the question is seen to be answered; otherwise the background Stackexchange community process will keep serving your question onto the question queue at intervals. See http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found How to fix it.

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/hdparm.conf
```

add at the bottom

```
/dev/sr0 {
    dma = on
}
```

reboot